# $\{\textbf{u}_i \textbf{u}_i^T\}_{i=1}^k$ linearly independent implies $k\leq \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ if $\{\textbf{u}_i\}_{i=1}^k$ equiangular.

Tags: linear-algebra

We call a collection of vectors $\{\textbf{u}_i\}_{i=1}^k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\textit{equiangular}$ if $\textbf{u}_i^T\textbf{u}_j=1$ if $i=j$ and $=\alpha$ if $i\neq j$ (here $\alpha\in (0,1)$ is fixed). Define $A_i=\textbf{u}_i \textbf{u}^T_i$ for each $i$ (an $n\times n$ matrix). I would like to show that if the matrices $\{A_1, \dots, A_k\}$ are linearly independent, then $k\leq \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

If $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^k$ are linearly independent, then for any $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^k\subset \mathbb{R}$, then 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k a_i \textbf{u}_{i,l}\textbf{u}_{i,j}\neq 0
$$ 
for some choice of $l,j$. Note that $\textbf{u}_{i,j}$ denotes the $j$'th entry of the vector $\textbf{u}_i$.

I am not sure how to proceed from here. Anyone have any advice or hint?

Comment: your matrices $A_i$ are real symmetric -- this is a vector space with dimension $\binom{n+1}{2}$, if the $A_i$ are known to be linearly independent then it immediately follows that you can't have more than $\binom{n+1}{2}$ of them

Comment: @user8675309 Right! I can't believe I completely over-looked that. If you answer the question with this, I'll accept/vote for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

real symmetric matrices live in a vector space with $\binom{n+1}{2}$ linearly independent vectors in it.  (It suffices to check for isomorphic vector space of upper triangular matrices and consider using standard basis vectors to generate the space $\mathbf e_r\mathbf e_j^T$   for $j\in\{1,2,...,n\}$ and $1\leq r \leq j$)

so if you have $k$ linearly independent symmetric matrices $A_i$, then it follows immediately that $k \leq \binom{n+1}{2}$ as a basis can be defined as a set of linearly independent vectors with maximal cardinality.